How to specify the p1 dB of an amplifier?
I am measuring the gain of a class AB power amplifier vs its output power and I see that in the linear region its gain is a steady 14 dB
When it approaches the nonlinear region there is an increase in gain so it reaches 15 dB before it starts falling to lower values and saturates
Would the P1 dB point be when the gain falls back to 14 dB or when it falls down to 13 dB? (one dB below the steady linear gain at 14 dB)
Why is this gain "boost" occurring especially in class AB amplifiers?

Why don't you specify it in terms of IP3? or perhaps IM3 at your maximum specified power? It doesn't necessarily means that maximum power of your amplifier, hopefully that's more than your needed spec.

Both definitions of P1dB can be used. This makes it ambiguous in cases where the gain is not monotonically decreasing with power.
If the gain goes up in the low-power region, then stays constant over a fairly large power region and then drops, it would be reasonable to use your first definition (putting the P1dB point where gain falls back to 14 dB in your example). But if the gain is flat almost everywhere, then has a narrow peak and immediately after that starts dropping, opinions may differ on which definition should be used.
Of course the problem can be avoided by specifying the linearity of an amplifier in another way, for instance by giving the AM-AM and AM-PM distortion curves, or power-dpendent IM3. But then it is not summarized in one number...
As for the question why some amplifiers have this behavior: this might be bipolar transistor amplifiers. The exponential transconductance of the bipolar transistor makes the gain go up with higher amplitude, but eventually there comes a point where voltage clipping due to the finite supply voltage will prohibit further output signal increase, so there the gain must drop.
